# Insert In Middle Of Class List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attr

I'm currently developing a JQuery application for my own personal use and as a shortcut, I am making a decision based on the last class in the list, which is always an identifier of sorts. That's been done in a number of places as:

```
$("#myelement").attr('class').split(/\s+/).pop()
```

The classes of the element are something like:

```
class1 class2 class_with_id
```

The issue is that now I have one place in the code where I'm trying to add a class to the list, which I would usually do like this:

```
$("#myelement").addClass("newclass")
```

However, that makes the classes look like this:

```
class1 class2 class_with_id newclass
```

And grabbing the identifier class later fails. I got it working with this:

```
$("#myelement").attr('class', "newclass " + $("#myelement").attr('class'))
```

That's adding it to the beginning:

```
newclass class1 class2 class_with_id
```

I have two questions, both related:

1. Is that the easiest/simplest way to accomplish adding it to the beginning?
2. Is there an easy way to add the class in the middle of the set without doing fancy string manipulation. I.e. say I wanted it to be the second last element:

   ```
   class1 class2 newclass class_with_id
   ```

Comment: I think that you have a problem, but the solution you are looking for is not the good one. Instead of `class_with_id`, you should probably use `data-with-id="id"`...

Comment: I'd agree with Karl-Andre, if you use data-attributes instead you won't need to worry about this. You can still target data-attributes in your CSS and JavaScript by using the [data-x] selector, so if you make it data-id you could call it with [data-id].

Comment: there are some who will swear that styling by data and not class is incorrect as the data attribute being dynamic is not semantic content. seems to me though that it is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments better to use **[data-* attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** for this purpose, because it's not a good practice to use class attribute like you do now it's not made for those cases, so for example replace :

```
$("#myelement").attr('class').split(/\s+/).pop();
```

By :

```
$("#myelement").data('with-id');
```

To get the attribute `data-with-id`, and add it by :

```
$("#myelement").data('with-id','some value');
```

Instead of :

```
$("#myelement").addClass("newclass");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Not that I am aware of.

   The class attribute is a string so I cannot see any way to do what are you looking for without some form of string manipulation.

   ```
   var original = 'class1 class2 class_with_id';
   var newClass = 'new_class';
   var index = original.lastIndexOf(' ');
   var updated = original.slice(0, index) + ' ' + newClass + original.slice(index);
   ```

   Will give you `class1 class2 new_class class_with_id`.

   Another option is to create your own splice or insert method for strings.

   ```
   String.prototype.insert = function (index, string) {
     if (index > 0)
       return this.substring(0, index) + string + this.substring(index, this.length);
     else
     return string + this;
   };

   var original = 'class1 class2 class_with_id';
   var newClass = 'new_class';
   var index = original.lastIndexOf(' ');
   var updated = original.insert(index, ' ' + newClass);
   ```

**Note:**
As Karl-André Gagnon has stated.. You would be better off using a custom data attribute as opposed to your current method. You may find that your method limits you from using any plugins which modify classes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why you are using the classes. But assuming that for some reason you can't use data like the some suggested and you prefer using classes, you could make a jquery function so as to be able to call it easily.

```
$.fn.addClassAt = function(index, newClass){
    var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    classArray.splice(index, 0, newClass);
    var newClassStr = classArray.join(' ');
    return $(this).attr('class', newClassStr);
}
```

You can now use this as

> $("#myElement").addClassAt(2, 'newClass')